# "Cannot find module routes" while running nodejs express framework command

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

When we run server.js file from the nodejs root we are encountering the error "cannot find module routes". This is a simple express framework project being executed from a Ubuntu nodejs environment.

**server/configure.js**

```
var path = require('path'),routes = require('routes'),
    exphbs = require('express-handlebars'),
    express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    errorHandler = require('errorhandler');

module.exports = function(app) {
app.use(morgan('dev'));
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':true}));
   app.use(bodyparser.json());
   app.use(methodOverride());
   app.use(cookieParser('some-secret-value-here'));
   routes(app);//moving the routes to routes folder.

   app.use('/public/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
   app.use(errorHandler());
}
    return app;
};
```

**root/server.js**

```
var express = require('express'); config =
require('./server/configure'); app = express();

 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3300); app.set('views', __dirname
 + '/views'); app = config(app);

 app.get('/',function(req,res){ res.send('Hello World');

 });

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {

    console.log('Server up: http://localhost:'+app.get('port'));     });
```

Comment: Why does your code have such weird formatting with multiple statements on the same line and statements broken across lines?  Also has very inconsistent indentation.  It's extremely hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

If `routes.js` is supposed to be your own routes module, then it appears the error is probably coming from this line of code and it's telling you that it can't find the routes.js module file:

```
routes = require('routes')
```

And, this would not be working because you're trying to load a local module without a proper path name.  If no path is specified, then it tries to load a global or built-in module.  If that module is in the current directory, then you can use this:

```
routes = require('./routes')
```